# iOS - Limit number of characters entered into UITextField while using speech-to-text (siri)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uitextview

How do we limit the number of characters entered into `UITextField` while using speech-to-text? I know how to limit it while using the keyboard, but I have no idea of how to do it while using speech-to-text (Siri), as the delegate `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is not being called.

Comment: I'm trying to limit number of characters user can enter into a text field. With keyboard I'm able to limit using above mentioned delegate call but with siri those delegate are not being called. Please let me know still if it is unclear.

Comment: Please let me know guys why are you down voting, so that I can correct it in future.

Comment: Its a valid question..

Answer (score 0):

The question is very much valid.

When using Siri, iOS fails to call:

```c
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

which robs you of the opportunity to disallow specific characters, impose length limits, etc by returning `NO`, or update parts of the GUI once the input is received.

In other forums, `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` has been reported to be called, but it is not doing so for me on 8.0 on my iPhone 6, so you can't even retrospectively change (truncated in the OP's case) the text once it's entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```c
if((textField.text.length + string.length) >= numberOfCharactersAllowed){
    return NO;
}
else{
    return YES;
}
```

When you are using Siri, the `UITextField` delegate gets fired when you are done. You can handle it like this.